# Heating bread in the microwave oven and wetting

Tags: bread, microwave, reheating

I have a problem when heating bread in the microwave oven. I place it on the glassy rotated bed of the oven, it get heated very well, but there is a lot of moisture are formed at the bottom of the bread (the contact between the glass and it).

How could I eliminate this wetting effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main strategies I employ to combat sweating in the microwave.

**Microwave the item in short intervals**, rotating in between each round. This will help steam dissipate rather than collect on the glass. Using a lower power might also help the item heat more evenly and lose less water.

**Place a paper towel or tea towel under the item.** This will collect the moisture so it doesn't pool and make things soggy.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding some kitchen paper underneath the bread to stop this from happening.

It is likely that the steam from the bread will be condensing on the colder microwave plate which then soaks back into the bread.